# Python - CUSTOMTKINTER How can I make both these elements appear in the same row?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

```py
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="Username: ")
label.pack(padx=(10, 5), pady=10, side=customtkinter.TOP, anchor=customtkinter.W)
entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame)
entry1.pack(padx=(0, 10), pady=10, side=customtkinter.TOP, expand=True, fill="x")
```

I've tried messing around with the side and anchor, but can't seem to get it to work.

Using `customtkinter` in Python, how can I make these 2 elements go on the same row?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZx4f.png)

Comment: Please do not post links to external sites with your screenshot. Instead, use the built-in image upload on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. I've used `grid` geometry manager instead of `pack`.

```
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="Username: ")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(10, 5), pady=10, sticky=customtkinter.W)
entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0, 10), pady=10, sticky="ew")
```

Comment: This works well, thanks, but using grid, how can I get the entry element to stretch across to the end of the window? before I was using expand.

Comment: You have to use columnconfigure method to configure the column to take up all remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

- Switched from .pack ---> .grid
- Used columnconfigure method to add weight to columns

[Final Result:]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Gzf.png

**Code:**

```py
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("650x175")
root.title("Bazaar Bot - Login")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=50)
root.resizable(False, False)

#Username
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="Username: ")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(15, 0), pady=10, sticky=customtkinter.W)
entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0, 10), pady=10, sticky="ew")
#Password
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="Password: ")
label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(15, 0), pady=10, sticky=customtkinter.W)
entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(0, 10), pady=10, sticky="ew")
```

Thanks, @Gihan

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways to do this: use `grid` and place both widgets on the same row. Or, use `pack` and place both widgets in a frame.

The following two examples should yield identical results both visually and in how they behave when the frame is resized due to the window being resized.

### Using pack

For me, the easiest way is to create a frame, then use `pack` to arrange the two widgets side-by-side. You can then add the frame to your larger program in whatever way makes the most sense: `pack`, `grid`, etc.

The advantage to using `pack` over `grid` in this specific case is that it's slightly simpler if you only need to group two widgets together.

Your code is already using a frame, so all you need to do is use the `side` parameter to put the two widgets side-by-side (assuming there aren't other widgets in the frame). Notice in the following example how it uses `fill` and `expand` to get the entry widget to expand to use all available space.

```
label.pack(side="left", padx=(10, 5))
entry1.pack(padx=(0, 10), side="right", fill="x", expand=True)
```

With that, you can add any other widgets to the window and then treat the frame as if it was a stand-alone widget.

```
frame.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
```

### Using grid

Like with `pack`, you can create a frame to contain both the entry and the label, and then you can treat the frame as if it was a custom widget.

The advantage to using `grid` instead of `pack` is that with `grid` it becomes much easier to align multiple labels and entry widgets. Just put each pair on a separate row. With `pack` you would need to use multiple frames to get the same effect.

The trick to using `grid` is that you need to give a weight to any row or column that you want to be allocated any extra space so that it will grow if its parent has extra space. You can use the `sticky` attribute similar to `pack`'s `fill` attribute to get the widget to "stick" to one or more sides.

```
frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(10, 5))
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew", padx=(0, 10))
```

---

[image: screenshot]